# Write CMS encoded PEM with Bouncycastle

Tags: content-management-system, bouncycastle, pem, pkcs#7

I have used the following source code and successfully generated a PKCS7 encoded PEM but i need to generate a CMS encoded based on RFC7468 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#page-11. Based on the RFC, CMS encoded PEM is recommended. Please help if you know the answer, thanks in advance.

```
    ContentSigner sha256Signer = new     JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WITHECDSA").setProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()).build(key);

    CMSTypedData     msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data.getBytes(charset));
    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
            new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(
            sha256Signer, new X509CertificateHolder(x509Cert)));

    gen.addCertificates(certStore);
    CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, true);
    // Generate PKCS7 PEM
    ContentInfo ci = signedData.toASN1Structure();
    
    StringWriter signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JcaPEMWriter pemWrt = new JcaPEMWriter(signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter);
    pemWrt.writeObject(ci);
    pemWrt.flush();
    pemWrt.close();
```